# Can I change windows 10 to 11 by just update the windows?

Tags: windows

Can I change windows 10 to 11 by just update the windows? this should be done so easy

Comment: Not a lawyer. Check out the Google Developer Policy and Distribution Agreement.

But from a technical standpoint, there is no need to upload two different apps since showing different languages can be handled by android and the play store automatically.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about licensing, not programming or software development. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do that when you can easily translate the app using strings.xml. I have my app uploaded with single APK and supports 7 languages. Its very easy to maintain.
Yes you can upload multiple APK's with different package names but sooner or later google will remove all apps that are similar in content just like appstore did.
I would suggest go for the right approach rather than work around.